# register device token manually with Firebase Notifications

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I would like to integrate my existing ionic ios app with the new [firebase notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) service. But i could not find any documentation about registering a device token manually with the rest api or web api.

Am i missing any new feature? Or is this not possible with the current libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Notifications at launch just supports Android and iOS.

For now, you can implement FCM directly for the web, see the [documentation for FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client), which will allow pushing messages via the API.